# How to set a div height in this situation?

Tags: css, html

How to set a div#wrap height in this situation?

```
<body style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;">
<div id="header" style="width:100%;height:50px;z-index:5;background:blue;padding:0;margin:0;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="wrap" style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;background:red;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;">
<div id="content" style="width:100%;height:2000px;padding:0;margin:0;">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer" style="width:100%;height:30px;z-index:5;background:green;padding:0;margin:0;">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: div#wrap height maybe 100%-div#header-div#footer, I want get div#wrap height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't actually set the height of a div height : `height:100%`, you might want to try `min-height:400px!important; _height:400px;`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

> http://jsfiddle.net/nkUwa/1/

try it in Firefox...  I don't know a way to make the header and footer a fixed height, and then have the wrap and content the "remaining area" like for the frameset usage...  But you can also style the header and footer as `position: absolute` and attached to the top and bottom of viewport, by using `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` respectively.